# Adding values inside a single cell in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, cell, addition

I have a column like so

```
       column 1       column 2
row1: 125+100+170    ,   0
row2: 125+100+130+30 ,   0
row3: 230+170        ,   0
row4: 230+130+30     ,   0
```

is there a way in oracle sql 11g to find the sum in each cell? i.e. 125+100+170 = 395

```
         desired output
       column 1    column 2
row1:     395    ,   0
row2:     385    ,   0
row3:     400    ,   0
row4:     390    ,   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but...

```
Select sum( regexp_substr (column1, '[^+]', 1, rownum) ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

as long as you also have a unique identifier in your table then the below will work...

```
select sum(single_element), column2
 from (SELECT distinct id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(column1, '[^\+]+', 1, level) AS single_element,
              column2
       FROM   test
       CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(column1, '\+') + 1
       order by id desc)
group by id, column2
order by id desc
```

see [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53bb4/12) to test

if you do not have a unique identifier in your table I don't know of a way of doing it.